# AWS SNS not attaching a Lambda trigger when the subscription is created via the SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I want to use a SNS subscription to trigger a Lambda function.
First I have created  a topic and subscription via the AWS SDK:

```js
    import {SubscribeCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sns";
    import {snsClient } from "./libs/snsClient.js";

    // Set the parameters
    const params = {
      Protocol: "lambda" /* required */,
      TopicArn: "TOPIC_ARN", //TOPIC_ARN
      Endpoint: "LAMBDA_FUNCTION_ARN", //LAMBDA_FUNCTION_ARN
    };

    const run = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await snsClient.send(new SubscribeCommand(params));
        console.log("Success.",  data);
        return data; // For unit tests.
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error", err.stack);
      }
    };
    run();
```

It is creating the subscription, but when I check the Lambda, this sub is not appearing as a Lambda trigger.
[image: empty trigger]

When I create the subscription manually without using the SDK it's working.
[image]

I would like to know why my subscription that created with the SDK is not showing in the Lambda's trigger.

Comment: But does sns trigger the lambda or it also does not work?

Comment: lambda is work normally when it's have a trigger(that created manually) and i publish notification to topic. but when i created by sdk it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the IAM permissions.  SNS needs explicit permission to invoke your Lambda.

See [How do I subscribe a Lambda function to an Amazon SNS topic in the same account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-subscribe-sns-topic-same-account/) in the docs.  The `lambda add-permission` CLI step from the example is the same as the [AddPermissionCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lambda/classes/addpermissioncommand.html) in the SDK Lambda client.  Provide your SNS topic's ARN.

Comment: Thanks fedonev you save my day. now it's working .

Comment: Thank you both, you just saved my day too! I find it odd that adding a subscription via the console automagically handles the permissions, but that this is effectively an undocumented manual step with the SDK...

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who comes to this thread looking to automate  using CDK, here's how can you automate everything about the stack and not use the CLI to add the missing pieces.

I ran into a similar issue recently. I needed to add SNS as a trigger, add the necessary permission to the lambda and add the lambda as a subscription to the SNS topic.

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as sns from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns';

export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
     const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'Subscription Topic', {
       fifo: false,
       topicName: 'subscription-events-topic',
    });

    // Get a reference to the existing lambda
    const subscriptionLambda = lambda.Function.fromFunctionName(
      this,
      'ExistingLambda',
      'SubscriptionEventsLambda' // <- The name of the existing lambda
    );

    // subscribe the lambda function to this topic
    new sns.CfnSubscription(this, 'Lambda Subscription', {
      protocol: 'lambda',
      endpoint: subscriptionLambda.functionArn,
      topicArn: topic.topicArn,
    });

    // allow SNS to invoke the lambda
    new lambda.CfnPermission(this, 'Allow SNS invocation', {
      action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
      principal: 'sns.amazonaws.com',
      functionName: subscriptionLambda.functionName,
      sourceArn: topic.topicArn,
    });
  }
}
```

I tried using other constructs such as `lambda.addPermission` and `topic.addSubscription` but for some reason they didn't work.

I got to this SO thread looking for a solution to this problem but couldn't find any.

For anyone that lands here, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was provisionning the Lambda with Terraform and had the same issue.

I had to add the following permissions in order to see the proper link in the Function Overview section of the Lamba referring the Cloudwatch triggers/subscriptions.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch_general" {
    statement_id  = "myamq-datadog-forwarder-CloudWatchLogsPermission-general"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = "myamq-datadog-forwarder"
    principal     = "logs.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn    = "arn:aws:logs:${local.region}:${local.account_id}:log-group:${local.amq_general_log_group_name}:*"
}


resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch_audit" {
    statement_id  = "myamq-datadog-forwarder-CloudWatchLogsPermission-audit"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = "myamq-datadog-forwarder"
    principal     = "logs.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn    = "arn:aws:logs:${local.region}:${local.account_id}:log-group:${local.amq_audit_log_group_name}:*"
}
```

and in local variables I set:

```
locals{
    // link to log
    amq_general_log_group_name =  "/aws/amazonmq/broker/${aws_mq_broker.myamq.id}/general"
    amq_audit_log_group_name =  "/aws/amazonmq/broker/${aws_mq_broker.myamq.id}/audit"

}
```